# initialize matrix index in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, row

I have one program with MATLAB. I have 3 variable such as a, b and c.
c is matrix with 2 columns and 10000 rows. a is row index matrix c and b is index column matrix c. For example

```
 c=[1 2 3 4;
   5 6;
   7 8;
   9 10;
   11 12]
a=[2,4];
b=[1,2];
```

i want write c(a,b)=0 return c(2,1)=0 and c(4,2)=0.

```
 c= 1 2
   0 6
   7 8
   9 0
   11 12
```

but return

```
c=   1     2
 0     0
 7     8
 0     0
11    12
```

I don't use for and while.
this example is very small in matrix program c is double (3000*3000) and b, c is double(1*1085)

Comment: Have you got your answer?

Answer (score 1):

To me below is  working-

```
c(a(1,1),b(1,1)) = c(a(1,2),b(1,2))=0
```

Use indexing to get right elements from `a` and `b` and use this to change `c` for more on indexing see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html?refresh=true).

Output-

```
c =

    1    2
    0    6
    7    8
    9    0
   11   12
```

### EDIT

To use looping for large matrix use this-

```
close all;clear;clc
c=[1 2 ;
   5 6;
   7 8;
   9 10;
   11 12];
a=[2,4,3];
b=[1,2,2];
concated = [a;b];
sz = size(concated);
for i=1:sz(1,2)
    ind = concated(:,i);
   c(ind(1,1),ind(2,1)) = 0;
end
disp(c);
```

Output-

```
 1     2
 0     6
 7     0
 9     0
11    12
```

Comment: tank for answer but example is very  small in program matric .length of a , b 10000 rows.

Comment: and I don't use for or while because ellipse time very big

Comment: then could you edit the question esp including representative example of data you have

Comment: I refresh this question. please help me